# Sub panel grounding

Tags: grounding

I replaced an old FPE sub panel that has no ground wire with the feed. The main panel is a new 200 amp with a 100 amp breaker feeding the sub. The wire is #2 copper ( 2 hots and one neutral in 1 1/4" EMT conduit). I ran a separate ground wire #6 copper back to the main service. My question is can I connect to the ground rod or do I have to connect to the main ground bus inside the panel?

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate the neutral and grounding bars in the second panel.
2. Connect the neutral feeder to the neutral bar
3. Connect the grounding feeder to the grounding bar.
4. Connect one end of the grounding electrode conductor to the grounding electrode (ground rod).
5. Connect the other end of the grounding electrode conductor to the grounding bar in the panel.
6. Connect each ungrounded (hot) conductor to the main lugs.

Answer (score 0):

According to code the sub needs to have the ground and neutral isolated to prevent objectionable current on the ground.

Comment: For other reasons, too.  Especially if ground rods are involved.